# SQL Case Statement: Inside Where Clause

Tags: sql, where-clause, case-statement

I have read some other Q&A about case statements inside the 'WHERE' clause, but I cannot truly understand how to use it. I will post below a snippet of the code. I believe I am ignorant of a fundamental principle concerning how to use a case statement, and this is why the code will not compile/run. I appreciate any help.

```
where i.status IN ('CR','L','O')
and i.FGCs > 0
and i.LastShpd > CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(11),DATEADD(DAY,-180,GETDATE()),113) AS datetime) 
and (Case
    When n.OnOrder IN ('0', '')
    Then i.OnOrder = 0 or i.LastShpd < CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(11),DATEADD(DAY,-21,GETDATE()),113) AS datetime)))
    End)
```

Order by i.LastShpd desc

To explain what I have above, I already got the appropriate 'SELECT' and 'FROM' statement. Now I am filtering the results based on those the shown variables (ecx LastShpd). What I wanted the case statement to do was: When n.OnOrder = 0, I want to keep only the rows where i.OnOrder = 0 or if i.LastShpd has been greater than 21 days.

Comment: you need to add an logic after the end  and (Case
    When n.OnOrder IN ('0', '')
    Then i.OnOrder = 0 or i.LastShpd < CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(11),DATEADD(DAY,-21,GETDATE()),113) AS datetime)))
    End)  =  "Something"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need a Case for this:

```
where i.status IN ('CR','L','O')
and i.FGCs > 0
and i.LastShpd > CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(11),DATEADD(DAY,-180,GETDATE()),113) AS datetime) 
and (
     (n.OnOrder IN ('0', '') and i.OnOrder = 0) 
 or i.LastShpd < CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(11),DATEADD(DAY,-21,GETDATE()),113) AS datetime)
    )
```

Re-reading your question maybe is this other way:

```
where i.status IN ('CR','L','O')
and i.FGCs > 0
and i.LastShpd > CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(11),DATEADD(DAY,-180,GETDATE()),113) AS datetime) 
and (
     n.OnOrder Not IN ('0', '') 
    or i.OnOrder = 0 
    or i.LastShpd < CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(11),DATEADD(DAY,-21,GETDATE()),113) AS datetime)
    )
```

Comment: That is a much better solution. Thank you

Comment: @StevenDuncan - glad it helped. I find CASE more useful on the Select side than on the Where side.

Answer (score 1):

When using a `CASE` within a `WHERE` clause, you still need to have both sides of the operation defined (i.e. [CASE CONDITION] = [SOMETHING]). This can get tricky depending on what you want to do, but the easiest thing is to have your case statement execute as a true/false type of condition so that you end up with [CASE] = 1 or [CASE] = 0.

In your case (accidental pun!):

```
where i.status IN ('CR','L','O')
and i.FGCs > 0
and i.LastShpd > CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(11),DATEADD(DAY,-180,GETDATE()),113) AS datetime) 
and (Case
    When n.OnOrder IN ('0', '') AND (i.OnOrder = 0 or i.LastShpd < CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(11),DATEADD(DAY,-21,GETDATE()),113) AS datetime)) 
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    End) = 1
```

Of course as another answer has pointed out, a case is not really necessary in this particular instance. However, if you had more complex conditions this could be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for explaining cases to me. I did not realize that you had to set it equal to something. This will be helpful as I continue to learn SQL.

Comment: @StevenDuncan you only have to compare when using it in a `WHERE` clause. You can also use `CASE` in a `SELECT` and then you wouldn't do the comparison at all. Interestingly enough, you can also use `CASE` in an  `ORDER BY` to do dynamic ordering. How you structure the SQL depends on the particular context.